# how to count number of items selected and send it to textview in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What I am trying to do is I want to count the number of items that have been selected by the user and display it to text-view but that text-view is in Fragment, not a part of RecyclerView rows I just want to get selected count data to that text-view. The text-view is below RecyclerView...

Please help me out...

Thanks!!!

Comment: when app user select or unselect an item from recycle view then update your text view. if you need help with code then please write your code in your question.

Comment: can you send the screenshot of what you implemented ?@Mahi